# difference between FetchMode and FetchType

Tags: hibernate, jpa, fetch

what is the difference in  specifying  `lazy = "true"` and  using `fetch = "select" or "join"` ? which one is preferred over the other ?

regards
jayendra

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Let's say we have entities like this:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Parent {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="parent", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    private List<Child> child;    
    //getter setters
}


@Entity
@Table
public class Child {    
    @Id
    private Long id;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Parent parent;

    //getter setter
}
```

In the example above, when getting `Parent` entity, hibernate will automatically load all `child` entities eagerly using join. On the other hand, when you fetch `Child`, `Parent` entity won't be selected unless you call it explicitly in your code `child.getParent()`.

FetchType (Lazy/Eager) tells whether we want entity to be loaded eagerly or lazy, when there's call in code.

FetchMode (Select/Join) tells whether we want our entity to be loaded with additional select or in one query with join or subselect.

Comment: Found this online. Very helpful.
http://www.solidsyntax.be/2013/10/17/fetching-collections-hibernate/

Comment: Tried the same, but running multiple queries even after specifying `@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)`, however works in single query in case of SUBSELECT

Answer (score 34):

**FetchMode** : It defines **`how`** hibernate (using which strategy, e.g. Join, SubQuery etc) will fetch data from database.

**FetchType** : It defines **`whether`** hibernate will fetch the data or not.

## **UPDATES** (as per suggestions from comments)

`FetchMode` isn't only applicable with `FetchType.EAGER`. The rules are as follows: a) if you don't specify `FetchMode`, the default is `JOIN` and `FetchType` works normal, b) if you specify `FetchMode.JOIN` explicitly, `FetchType` is ignored and a query is always eager, c) if you specify `FetchMode.SELECT` or `FetchMode.SUBSELECT`, `FetchType.Type` works normal

Comment: FetchMode isn't only applicable with FetchType.EAGER. The rules are as follows: a) if you don't specify FetchMode, the default is JOIN and FetchType works normal, b) if you specify FetchMode.JOIN explicitly, FetchType is ignored and a query is always eager, c) if you specify FetchMode.SELECT or FetchMode.SUBSELECT, FetchType.Type works normal.

Comment: To add on to @DawidStępień, If you forget to `JOIN FETCH` all `EAGER` associations, `Hibernate` is going to issue a `secondary select` for each and every one of those which, in turn, can lean to `N+1 query issues`. For this reason, you should prefer `LAZY` associations. - [link](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/chapters/fetching/Fetching.html)

Comment: @DawidStępień, please make your comment as answer so that it will be more clearly seen. Thanks!

Comment: @DawidStępień If FetchType.LAZY is specified, will it be necessary to specify FetchMode,SELECT? What's the difference between using @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT) and
@ManyToOne(fetch = LAZY) together vs using only @ManyToOne(fetch = LAZY)?

Comment: Regarding the statement below "updates": It looks like a copy&paste from a Baeldung's page. If you open the hibernate sourcecode [here](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/5.0/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/cfg/annotations/CollectionBinder.java#L682) you can see that in case the fetchMode is not specified, FetchType is the driver and a FetchType = Lazy forces the FetchMode to SELECT not to JOIN.