# difference between @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT) and fetch = FetchType.LAZY

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I want to know why we need to use both @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT) and fetch = FetchType.LAZY .fetchMode.select itself tells that all association should be loaded as lazy then why another term?
`

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "stock")
@Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)
@Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
@BatchSize(size = 10)
public Set<StockDailyRecord> getStockDailyRecords() {
return this.stockDailyRecords;
}
```

`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [difference between FetchMode and FetchType](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25821718/difference-between-fetchmode-and-fetchtype)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FetchType.LAZY`: refers to `when` Hibernate will fetch the association and entities.
`@Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)`: refers to `how` Hibernate will fetch the association and entities.

Comment: If `fetchType` is `LAZY` then this implicitly assumes that `FetchMode` will be `SELECT` (or `SUBSELECT` if you set it explicitly). But I can't imagine how e.g. `FetchType.LAZY` + `FetchMode.JOIN` can work together. If it is joined already, it is not lazy by definition. The same is for `FetchType.EAGER` + `FetchMode.SELECT`/`FetchMode.SUBSELECT`. So, the real answer I think is that `FetchMode` is actually an "extension" to `FetchType`. `FetchType.EAGER` and `FetchMode.JOIN` is actually exactly the same. And `FetchType.LAZY` can be one of two types: `FetchMode.SELECT` and `FetchMode.SUBSELECT`.